# Bluebird Promise: any() collection return value undefined

Tags: javascript, promise

Using bluebird promises, I am trying to check if a certain version of a file exists (always only ONE of those files exists but i don't know which one). To speed things up, I am using the any() collection to get all checking out concurrently:

```
 Promise.any([
     fs.existsAsync('./foo/image1.jpg'),
     fs.existsAsync('./foo/image2.gif'),
     fs.existsAsync('./foo/image3.png')
 ]).then(function(result) {
     console.log(result); //remains undefined
 });
```

I am always getting an undefined result. According to ([How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/30180679#30180679)) this is normal behaviour of a resolved promise. Still, I need to know, which of my three promises resolved or maybe I just can't use any() for that purpose?

Comment: `existsAsync` [doesn't promosify properly](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/418), use `statAsync`.

Comment: Oh, good to know o0 Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to add a resolve message to each promise? Using stat does not give me the right info to clearly identify the related file.

Comment: `existsAsync` is deprecated, it should not be used in new code.

Comment: Yes, I switched to statAsync in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

The callback for `fs.exists()` does not follow the expected calling convention of `callback(err, value)` so it doesn't work with generic promisify.  It uses just `callback(value)`.

You could either use `fs.statAsync()` instead or you could create your own promisification for `fs.exists()` that would work properly.

Of course, `fs.exists()` is deprecated anyway for race condition reasons so you should perhaps rethink your tactic here anyway.

Here's a properly promisified `fs.existsAsync()`:

```
fs.existsAsync = function(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        fs.exists(path, resolve);
    });
}
```

You would assign this after you've done the general promisification of the `fs` module to replace the wrong `fs.existsAsync` that Bluebird did automatically.